# Javascript Call PHP in Sister Folder

Tags: php, javascript

I have the following tree:

```
root
  -js_src
  -php_src
  -images
```

Now, how do i reliably call the PHP files from the Javascript? The PHPs are located in the `php_src` folder while the javascript is in the `js_src` folder.

Comment: php can't run javascript functions. php is executed on the server and javascript runs in the browser (after the php has been rendered to the page). if that's what you're asking?

Comment: that is totally off the mark as to what I am asking...I just want to know what is the best way to reference the PHP files from the Javascript files...since they are in separate folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Absolute URL:    http://yourserver.com/php_src/script.php
Relative-rooted: /php_src/script.php

File-based relative: ../php_src/script.php
File-based absolute: /path/to/your/site/php_src/script.php
```

Comment: Ok, will try the Relavite-root version, that looks the best to me. Now, to add a little bit...I am calling the PHP from jQuery via the `$.getJSON()` function. Any issues beacuse of that? I assume `$.getJSON("/php_src/script.php"...` is all I need to do?

Comment: Should be. You can always check the server's access/error logs to see what's going on.